# Comparing Random Sets of Numbers in Two Columns

Tags: javascript

The goal here is to compare two sets of ten randomly generated numbers with Javascript as to whether they're greater than, less than, or equal to each other.

I have this so far:

```
document.write("Comparing Numbers from Corresponding Lists: <br>");

var list1=new Array();
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
list1[i]=Math.round(Math.random()*100);
}

var list2=new Array();
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
list2[i]=Math.round(Math.random()*100);
}

if (list1>list2) {
document.write(list1 + " is greater than " + list2);
} else if (list1<list2) {
document.write(list1 + " is less than " + list2);
} else if (list1=list2) {
document.write(list1 + " is equal to " + list2);
}
```

What this does is display the following:

```
Comparing Numbers from Corresponding Lists: 
15,4,30,39,46,8,91,85,64,17 is less than 97,78,32,50,60,36,42,6,12,80
```

However I need it in two columns (like a table with two columns and ten rows). A classmate had suggested putting the if/else if statement in a for() loop, but I'm not sure what statements to put in the parenthesis after the for; I thought maybe something like this for the first two statements (the third I'm at a loss):

```
for (var list1 = 0, list2 = 0; list1.length, list2.length; ...) {
```

Sorry if this is really basic/obvious, I'm just really stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the < and > and == operators are not supported at the array level, so you have to compare each member of each list individually. Also, note that you have a single = operator (which is assignment), but you're using it in the == operator context (which is the comparison operator).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to compare the individual numbers in the array, you can use a basic loop and check:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    if (list1[i] > list2[i]) { //its greater! }
    else if (list1[i] < list2[i]) { //its less! }
    else { //they must be equal }
}
```

Also, fair warning, `document.write` is going to rewrite your page each time!

Comment: I have to have it read "is greater than," etc. Is there a better way to display that string than `document.write`?

I have this now:
`for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    if (list1[i] > list2[i]) { document.write(list1+" is greater than "+list2 }
    else if (list1[i] < list2[i]) { document.write(list1+" is less than "+list2 }
    else { document.write(list1+" is equal to "+list2 }
}`

and now the page isn't displaying anything at all. I'm guessing it's the `document.write` stuff.

Comment: I fixed the previous code where I was missing parenthesis and semicolons (it's late, sorry) and now it's displaying this: `15,4,30,39,46,8,91,85,64,17 is less than 97,78,32,50,60,36,42,6,12,80` except there's ten sets of those now (all with random numbers, some less than, some equal to, and some greater than.)

Comment: I've figured it out. I just needed to add `[i]` after my variables in `document.write` and some line breaks because it was displaying the whole array instead of one number at a time. Thanks for the help everyone.